# How to parse descendents of serialized xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I serialized an XSD file in c#, I want to parse all the properties which are the descendants. How can I do that?

```
var path = Path.Combine("E:\\Sources\\ADQ\\trunk\\WebSite\\Tests\\Formulaire   web -DropBox v5\\Formulaire web", "xsd\\XML_METADATA.xml");
MetadataEntity metadata = new MetadataEntity();
metadata = MetadataEntity.Loadfromfile(path);
```

Comment: You need to add a lot more information.  What does the XML look like?  What is a property?  What is `MetadataEntity`?

Comment: Lot of different ways.  The best method can vary depending on the amount of data you are extracting from the XML.  Probably serialized is going to be the best method in your case since you want to extract "all" the properties.

Comment: all descenedent elements of metadataEntity become propreties when it is serialized. it's look like
<metadata>
<language>
  <characterSet> </characterSet>
<langage>
<fileIdentifier> 
</fileIdentifier>
.
.
.
</metadata>

after serialization  they become like that : metadata.laguage , metadata.fileIdentifier....etc.